# User friendly way to supply a large amount of parameters to a python script

Tags: python, user-interface

So, I have a experiment which I have programmed (cognitive science).

The experiment has many parameters that need to be specified, i.e.,
number of blocks (*sections* in the experiment), color of stimuli in each block, length of each block, etc.

I have 'machinery' to handle all of these parameters in the code, but what I'd like is a user-friendly way of supplying them to the script. There are about a dozen settings for each 'block'. So, for a 3 block experiment, that would mean 36 settings that need to be specified.

---

My current approach is to read in a .csv that looks something like this:

```
                     Block1        Block2
NumberOfTrials        100            40
StimuliColors   ['red','green']    'green'
SoundOnOrOff          Off            On
```

---

Is there a way that is more user friendly than requiring the person who's using the program to generate a 'settings csv'?
Something that they could do in the browser, perhaps?

Comment: You could provide a browser-based UI, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not generate an iPython/Jupyter notebook: This could have fields to populate, explanatory text, validation of the field values and buttons/cells to a) write to a .csv file for later use and b) write the file and run your code & display the results.